# ¿Cómo utilizar currencyPipe para peso Argentino en Angular?

Tags: angular

En mi **formulario reactivo** tengo un **input** para el precio, a medida que el usuario va escribiendo el precio, este toma por defecto el formato de dolar, pero necesito que por defecto tome el **formato peso Argentino.**

**componet.ts**

```js
import { FormBuilder, FormGroup, Validators } from '@angular/forms';
import { CurrencyPipe } from '@angular/common';

form: FormGroup;

 constructor(
    private currencyPipe: CurrencyPipe,
    private formBuilder: FormBuilder
  ) { 
    this.buildForm();

    // cuando escribe el precio 
    this.form.valueChanges.subscribe(formulario => {
      if(formulario.price){
        this.form.patchValue({
          price: this.currencyPipe.transform(formulario.price.replace(/\D/g, '').replace(/^0+/, ''), 'USD', 'symbol', '1.0-0')
        }, {emitEvent: false});
      }
    })
  }

 buildForm() {
    this.form = this.formBuilder.group({
      // name: ['', [Validators.required, Validators.maxLength(50)]],
      // year: ['', [Validators.required, Validators.min(1500),Validators.max(this.year)]],
      price: ['', [Validators.required]],     
    });
  }
```

Aca **component.html** (solo muestro el input del precio para ahorrar código).

```html
<form [formGroup]="form">
 <label>Precio</label>
 <input type="text" formControlName="price" placeholder="$">
</form>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sería interesante que mencionaras con cuál versión de Angular estás trabajando. Sin embargo, asumiré que estás trabajando con la versión 11 (última).

Como indica la documentación, puedes usar [formatCurrency()](https://angular.io/api/common/formatCurrency), ya que lo estás implementando desde el código, no la plantilla.

Estructura de la sobrecarga (según documentación):

```js
formatCurrency(
  value: number,
  locale: string,
  currency: string,
  currencyCode?:
  string,
  digitsInfo?: string
): string
```

Cabe mencionar que `currencyCode` recibe código [ISO-4217](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_4217) de la divisa que, en el caso de Argentina, es **ARS**.

Ejemplo:

```js
import { formatCurrency } from '@angular/common';
... 
  public numeroConFormato = formatCurrency(parseFloat('1521.8'), 'en-US', 'ARS ', 'ARS', '4.2-2')
...
```

En este caso, asumimos que `locale` es `en-US`, pero puedes implementar otro teniendo la debida configuración i18n.

El tercer parámetro, `'ARS '`, es el prefijo del texto (puedes colocarlo como `'$'`).

El cuarto parámetro, `'ARS'` es el código ISO-4217

El último parámetro, es el formato de plantilla para el decimal. Su estructura es:

numeroMaximoDeEnteros.digitosMinimosDeLaFraccion/decimales-digitosMaximosDeLaFraccion/decimales

Es decir, según el ejemplo anterior (`4.2-2`):

`4`: número máximo de interos
`2`: número de decimales mínimo
`2`: número de decimales máximo

Resultado esperado según ejemplo:

```html
<p>{{ numeroConFormato }}</p>
```

Impreso como:

ARS 1,521.80

---

Dejo [estos](https://www.angularjswiki.com/angular/angular-decimal-pipe/) ejemplos de referencia, ya que hay más de una forma de implementar esta funcionalidad.

Comment: Gracias por la ayuda y tu explicacion! lo que no entiendo es como acoplar tu ejemplo en el formControl o en el this.form.valueChanges

Comment: @Claudio El ejemplo retorna un string con el formato, el mismo método lo puedes utilizar para parchar el valor de tu campo, siempre y cuando este sea una **cadena**, evidentemente, esto convertiría tu número a cadena, no aplica para campos numéricos, ya que estos, por defecto, tomarán la configuración numérica local con la respectiva API del navegador, lo cual no es posible de modificar con CurrencyPipe o formatCurrency()